# How to remove corners radius in drawable programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to remove corner radius programmatically. I don't know how to do it.

I'm creating ProgressBarCompat for change progress bar color with colorAccent but i don't know how to remove corner radius in progressBarDrawable in android api lower than 11.

Link to drawable: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/drawable/progress_horizontal.xml

Can I do it?

I'm using this to get the progress drawable:

```
LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable) getProgressDrawable();
Drawable progressDrawable = drawable.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress);
// and now i detect sdk version and call method to remove corners on this drawable (progressDrawable).
```